# How to pass a tcl script a string and interpret it properly

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to modify a tcl script that pushes bitfiles onto fpgas using xilinx's xsct tool.  Here's what it looks like:

```
connect hw_server TCP:127.0.0.1:3122
targets -set -filter {jtag_cable_name =~ "Digilent JTAG-HS2 21xxx" && name =~ "xc7*"}
fpga [lindex $argv 0]
after 100
targets -set -filter {jtag_cable_name =~ "Digilent JTAG-HS2 21xxx" && name =~ "Micro*"}
loadhw system.hdf
stop
dow [lindex $argv 1]
con -block
```

Now that I have multiple FPGAs, I'd like to make the jtag_cable_name an argument.  I've tried this to no avail:

```
connect hw_server TCP:127.0.0.1:3121
targets -set -filter {jtag_cable_name =~ [eval [lindex[$argv 0]] && name =~ "xc7*"}
fpga [lindex $argv 1]
after 100
targets -set -filter {jtag_cable_name =~ [eval [lindex[$argv 0]] && name =~ "Micro*"}
loadhw system.hdf
stop
dow [lindex $argv 2]
con -block
```

the call to the .tcl script looks like:

```
load_fpga.tcl "Digilent JTAG-HS2 21xxx" my_bitfile.bit my_elf.elf
```

How can I correctly pass the string and keep it in quotes like the original is?

Comment: You should be on track with @slebetman answer. However, you won't need that bit: `[eval [lindex[$argv 0]] `. This should just read `[lindex $argv 0]`. My guessing is that `eval` is an artefact of your attempts to turn the literal into an interpolated string again, to pick up the wording. Also not that syntactically, your `[eval ...]` is not correct. Whitespace missing between `lindex` and its first arg!

Comment: Now that I looked closer: `[$argv 0]` is just wrong, to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you don't realise is that in tcl, `{Hello World}` is a string.

If you are familiar with languages like Perl or Ruby than you would be familiar with the concept of literal and interpolated strings. In tcl, there are three syntaxes for strings:

1. Anything that doesn't contain a whitespace (space, tab, newline) is a string. Also, whitespace may be escaped. An escaped whitespace is not considered whitespace. The following are strings:

   ```
   hello
   hello\ world
   ```
2. Anything grouped by `"` are interpolated strings. Interpolated strings may contain variables or commands which will be evaluated and substituted. The following strings all say "hello world":

   ```
   set x hello

   "hello world"
   "$x world"
   "[set x] world"
   ```
3. Anything grouped by `{}` are literal strings. Literal strings aren't interpolated. That is, no variables or commands are evaluated. The following are literal strings:

   ```
   {hello world} ;# hello world
   {$x world}    ;# $x world
   ```

---

There are two things you can do to get what you want

1. Replace `{}` with `""`. This will simply make the literal string into an interpolated string:

   ```
   "jtag_cable_name =~ [eval [lindex[$argv 0]] && name =~ \"xc7*\""
   ```

   note how you need to escape the `"` inside the string.
2. Use the `subst` command. The `subst` command performs substitutions on a string:

   ```
   [subst {jtag_cable_name =~ [eval [lindex[$argv 0]] && name =~ "xc7*"}]
   ```

   The small advantage of this is you don't need to escape the `"`. Read the manual page for `subst`. It's highly flexible allowing you to select what type of things you want to substitute. For example it allows you to evaluate only commands but not the `$` syntax.

Comment: Note that the `{}` syntax is ALWAYS a string. For example you may think that the syntax for `if` is `if expression code else code` but it's actually `if string string else string`

Comment: Every value in Tcl is a string (well, at least serializable to a string; the builtin types all reliably convert to string and back transparently so we can safely pretend they're all just strings when we're not thinking about performance). Every word to every command is a Tcl value, even if it looks like a block of code, and including the name of the command itself. (Commands and variables aren't strings, but are named by strings and implemented by/contain strings.)

Comment: what's the purpose of `eval` here? I'd use `format` myself, to inject the argument into the string.

Comment: @glennjackman That comes from the OP's code. I try to make my answers contain the minimum change needed to fix an issue otherwise the answers will be longer. And as you can see, even with minimal change my answers tend to be long anyway because I also prefer to explain the fix as clearly as I can

Comment: You should at least correct the errors : `[eval [lindex[$argv 0]]`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
set jtag_cable_name [lindex $argv 0]
# ...
targets -set -filter [format {jtag_cable_name =~ "%s" && name =~ "xc7*"} $jtag_cable_name]
```

You can assign all the command line args like this:

```
lassign $argv  jtag_cable_name  bit_filename  elf_filename
```